# Semver compatible autoincrement the version number of a prerelease nupkg

Tags: .net-core, nuget, semantic-versioning

When we work on a new release of a nuget package we constantly need to produce a new prerelease build of the same nuget package multiple times a day.

To be able to consume the new build of the prerelease nupkg in our test applications it must get a new prerelease version with each and every build that is triggered by TFS. Otherwise the nuget package manager would not allow us to update the nuget package in the consuming solution, because it would not detect an update.

The common way this is solved is to add some sort of autoincrementing suffix with the same character width to the prerelease version suffix of the nuget package. For example asp.net core [solves is this way](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore/3.0.0-preview-19058-0284):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore 3.0.0-preview-19058-0284`

They add a suffix that is always 5 characters wide and another one that is always 4 characters wide and they make sure that they increment upon each build in a semver compatible way.

How can I achieve the same thing using on-premise TFS 2018, i.e.

1. How can I generate a number (just one number suffix would suffice in my case) that always has the same width (by adding leading zeros) and that always increments.
2. How can I append this number to the nupkg version after the prerelease suffix.

Answer (score 1):

I use the build date to suffix prerelease version.
In the csproj :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageOutputPath Condition="$(PackageOutputPath) == ''">$(OutputPath)</PackageOutputPath>
    <Title>MyAssembly</Title>
    <Version>1.0.0-$(Configuration)-$(Platform)-$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(yyyyMMdd-HHmmss))</Version>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2019</Copyright>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```